# I installed tortoisehg on ubuntu, but why can't i see the GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, tortoisehg

I used tortoisehg on Windows in the past, the GUI is very friendly.

Now i move on Ubuntu(11.10), i installed it using following command:

```
apt-get install mercurial python-nautilus tortoisehg
```

After the installation, i could use hg command, but i didn't know how to start the GUI(There was no related items in the right-click menu at all).

PS:I am using root account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you run [`thg`](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.2/quick.html) to do just about everything with Tortoisehg.

I strongly recommend *not* using `root` for everything. That makes it far to easy to accidentally shoot yourself in the foot. (If I had a dollar for every time I heard someone accidentally delete something *really important* because they were running as `root`, I'd have a good pile of tacos right now.)

Answer (score 3):

The Nautilus extensions require restarting your graphical server. Log out and back in for this.

You can also invoke the GUI via the terminal, this is how I use Tortoise HG. Pass the command you'd normally use for the command line client. For example:

```
$ hgtk ci
# commit dialog pops up
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem too so I wrote something to fix it.

just run this in the terminal to set up

```
START=$(pwd)
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
mkdir -p ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/
cd ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/slashuer/nautilus_mercurial_scripts
mv nautilus_mercurial_scripts/Mercurial/ .
rm -R nautilus_mercurial_scripts/
cd $START
```

OK done, now just right click the folder/repo and look under scripts